# SQLite, mobile or browser of mobile

Tags: android, iphone, sqlite

well while planning a mobile application

a question comes in mind

SQLite!

is supported in many mobile browsers (IOS, blackberry, android (I guess) )

so if all my app need is to save and restore presistent data (like notes, or schedule)

Is developing web app htmls + javascript that stores data in SQLite of browser

Is equivalent to creating a mobile app that using IOS, or android java, that stores data in mobile's SQLite ?

Comment: Equivalent in what sense? Do you want to access the data created by a web-app from a native app?

Comment: not really, but i wanna evaluate do I have to do native app or doing a html5 + javascript page is good enough for db CRUD operations app

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5's local storage is definitely an option here. It can definitely do CRUD stuff and is really simple to use. Here's a quick storage example:

```
var store = window.localStorage;
store.setItem('cow','moo');

# and to get it back:
store.getItem('cow')
```

If you're only storing small amounts of data then this is the best option. If you're doing more complicated stuff like joins or storing a large amounts of data then I'd consider a native database instead.